# How do you fill missing dates in a Polars dataframe (python)?

Tags: python, dataframe, missing-data, python-polars

I do not seem to find an equivalent for Polars library. But basically, what I want to do is **fill missing dates between two dates** for a big dataframe. It has to be Polars because of the size of the data (> 100 mill).

Below is the code I use for **Pandas**, but how can I do the same thing for **Polars**?

```
import janitor
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def missing_date_filler(d):
    
    
    df = d.copy()

    
    time_back = 1 # Look back in days
    td = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    helper = timedelta(days=time_back)
    
    max_date = (td - helper).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") # Takes todays date minus 1 day
    
    df_date = dict(Date = pd.date_range(df.Date.min(), 
                                        max_date, 
                                        freq='1D')) # Adds the full date range between the earliest date up until yesterday

    df =  df.complete(['Col_A', 'Col_B'], 
                      df_date).sort_values("Date") # Filling the missing dates
    
    
    return df
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`.upsample()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.upsample.html#polars.DataFrame.upsample)

Note that you can use the **`by`** parameter to perform the operation on a per-group basis.

```
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

df = pl.DataFrame({
   "date": [datetime(2023, 1, 2), datetime(2023, 1, 5)], 
   "value": [1, 2]
})
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬───────┐
│ date                | value │
│ ---                 | ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        | i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | 1     │
│ 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | 2     │
└─────────────────────┴───────┘
```

```
>>> df.upsample(time_column="date", every="1d")
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬───────┐
│ date                | value │
│ ---                 | ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        | i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | 1     │
│ 2023-01-03 00:00:00 | null  │
│ 2023-01-04 00:00:00 | null  │
│ 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | 2     │
└─────────────────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Correct, .upsample() is the one. For groups it is just for me to use by=["group_col_A", "group_col_B"]. If you could edit your answer to include by argument aswell would be cool.

Comment: I didn't notice any grouping in your example - I guess it's the `.complete()` method from pyjanitor doing it? I've made an edit to include a note - does that help?

Comment: Yes, .complete() helps with that. However, your answer was sufficient enough as it solved the problem. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Your data must be well sorted for upsample to work correctly, I noticed that there is a big difference between the results when sorting using sort and set_sorted as in the example from the [Polars documentation](https://docs.pola.rs/py-olars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.upsample.html).

Using set_sorted:

```
from datetime import datetime
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": [
            datetime(2021, 2, 1),
            datetime(2021, 4, 1),
            datetime(2021, 5, 1),
            datetime(2021, 6, 1),
            datetime(2021, 2, 1),
        ],
        "groups": ["A", "B", "A", "B", 'B'],
        "values": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    }
).set_sorted("time") ########## here 
df=df.upsample(
    time_column="time", every="1mo", by="groups", maintain_order=True
).select(pl.all().forward_fill())
df                         
>>> shape: (4, 3)
time    groups  values
datetime[μs]    str i64
2021-02-01 00:00:00 "A" 0
2021-03-01 00:00:00 "A" 0
2021-04-01 00:00:00 "A" 0
2021-05-01 00:00:00 "A" 2
```

Using sort:

```
from datetime import datetime
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": [
            datetime(2021, 2, 1),
            datetime(2021, 4, 1),
            datetime(2021, 5, 1),
            datetime(2021, 6, 1),
            datetime(2021, 2, 1),
        ],
        "groups": ["A", "B", "A", "B", 'B'],
        "values": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    }
).sort("time") ########## here
df=df.upsample(
    time_column="time", every="1mo", by="groups", maintain_order=True
).select(pl.all().forward_fill())
df
>>> shape: (9, 3)
time    groups  values
datetime[μs]    str i64
2021-02-01 00:00:00 "A" 0
2021-03-01 00:00:00 "A" 0
2021-04-01 00:00:00 "A" 0
2021-05-01 00:00:00 "A" 2
2021-02-01 00:00:00 "B" 4
2021-03-01 00:00:00 "B" 4
2021-04-01 00:00:00 "B" 1
2021-05-01 00:00:00 "B" 1
2021-06-01 00:00:00 "B" 3
```

Comment: There is a warning in the [`Expr.set_sorted()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.set_sorted.html#polars.Expr.set_sorted) docs: **Warning:** *"This can lead to incorrect results if this Series is not sorted!! Use with care!"* - It should probably be added to the `DataFrame.set_sorted` docs page as well.